# How to make border attached to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, next.js, frontend

I am making a front-end website. It contains wrapper with header, left "profile", center "main" and right "games" divs, and I can't get how to fix my border being above the end of page. Header, left and right divs serve as layout, while main should be scrollable.[View of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D52Ya.png)

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "profile main games";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.profile {
  grid-area: profile;
  width: 298px;
  height: 980px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.avatar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #343633;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.games {
  grid-area: games;
  width: 298px;
  height: 980px;
  background-color: #333333;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.main {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 1000px;
  grid-area: main;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 92.3px;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header className={ 'header'}>
  <br></br>
</header>
<div className={ 'wrapper'}>
  <div className={ 'profile'}></div>
  <div className={ 'main'}>{children}</div>
  <div className={ 'games'}></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your html tags too.

Comment: I created a snippet based on your code, please edit it so we can see the final output so we can debug your problem.

Comment: What border are you wanting to show? I note that .main is very tall.